# Error, when i try validate Json from response with schema in soapUI

Tags: json, rest, validation, soapui, json-schema-validator

i use sopaUI 5.0.0 with   libraries:

- btf 1.2
- jackson-annotations-2.0.1
- jackson-core-2.8.1
- jackson-coreutils-1.8
- json-schema-core-1.2.5
- json-schema-validator-2.2.6

I try do this code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingReport
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory



def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("getClientByID").getPropertyValue("response")
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
JsonNode invoiceJSON = mapper.readTree(response)

JsonNode invoiceSchemaJSON = mapper.readTree(new File("C:\\test\\resources\\schems\\client-card-rs.json"))
log.info( invoiceSchemaJSON)

JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault()

JsonSchema invoiceSchema = factory.getJsonSchema(invoiceSchemaJSON)
if (invoiceSchema.validInstance(invoiceJSON)) log.info("Response  Validated!")
else {
testRunner.fail(invoiceSchema.validate(invoiceJSON).toString())
}
```

But script crash with error at line:

```
 JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault()
```

First,issued error:

```
"write_bigdecimal_as_plain"
```

Later

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion
```

SoapUI error log:

```
2016-09-11 15:39:49,202 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfigurationBuilder.<init>(LoadingConfigurationBuilder.java:117)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfiguration.byDefault(LoadingConfiguration.java:151)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.<init>(JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.java:67)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder(JsonSchemaFactory.java:123)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault(JsonSchemaFactory.java:113)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory$byDefault.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script6.run(Script6.groovy:20)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:100)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:154)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Help pls.

Comment: did you try to import that jar `import com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion`

Comment: @user1207289   I try it, but the script still falls.

Comment: same error or new error?

Comment: @user1207289 same error, i'm not add to question first error("write_bigdecimal_as_plain") earlier.

Comment: use latest version of your libs

Comment: I've just come across the same problem. Did you find any solutions, Victor Yakimov? My lib versions are the following:

btf 1.2
jackson-annotations-2.2.3 / 2.9.2
jackson-core-2.2.3 / 2.9.2
jackson-databind-2.2.3 / 2.9.2
jackson-coreutils-1.8
json-schema-core-1.2.5
json-schema-validator-2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was using the **json-schema-validator-2.2.8-lib.jar** from **com.github.java-json-tools** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/2.2.8) instead of com.github.fge (which supported the project till its 2.2.6 version). It is important to use the package of libs provided instead of collecting all the relevant dependencies manually. Somehow it doesn't want to work correctly.

I am using SoapUI 5.2.1 on Docker container built on top of an OpenJDK 8 image.

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @LW001 thanks for the remark. I've just changed the question to an answear. I will bear that in mind for the future.